# Tests run in pipeline on Zalenium are more than four times slower than when running locally

Tags: selenium, karate, selenium-grid, zalenium

I am using the Karate framework to write UI tests. When I execute a suite locally, it takes about 20 minutes to run around 40 test cases.

However, when I run the build in the pipeline on Zalenium, it is taking about 2-3 hours. I am using Docker for each execution.

Is this expected? What are some strategies that can help?

Thank you in advance!